# how to stop fetching again image if already fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, lazy-loading

how to stop fetching again image if already fetch ? I am using below plugin to check whether element come in view port or not. but issue is when I scroll down it fetch image which is correct behaviour but when I move up it hide the image again . If I move down again it again fetch the image ?

how to prevent fetching again and again image . If already come in DOM don't remove .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer

```
import * as React from "react";
// @ts-ignore Wrong type
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import ScrollWrapper from "./elements/ScrollWrapper";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    threshold: 0
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "200vh" }}>eeeeee</div>
      <div ref={ref} className="inview-block">
        <h2>
          <img
            src={
              inView
                ? "https://inviewimaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Inview-Graphic.png"
                : null
            }
            alt=""
          />
        </h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

here is my code ... any suggestion ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/useinview-forked-74y015?file=/src/index.tsx:0-786

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in lazy loading capabilities that HTML5 has? They might solve your issue without needing to check `inView` at all.

Comment: but it is not working in all browser

Comment: I guess that depends on your use case, but most modern browsers support it for images. https://caniuse.com/?search=lazy%20loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set  triggerOnce:true in useInView
like this :

```
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    threshold: 0,
    triggerOnce:true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cache** and compare from **cache** that how many items are new to fetch